# ABAP CALL METHOD: meaning of 'static' and 'dynamic'

Tags: class, abap

I'm a little confused about the meaning of terms 'static' and 'dynamic' w.r.t. CALL METHOD in ABAP.

On the one hand, static refers to components of a class that can be accessed without instance.  Dynamic refers to access via the content of a field at runtime.

So, `(class)=>(meth)` would be a dynamic call to a static method?!

What are the inverse terms then?

- [one meaning of dynamic](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abapcall_method_meth_ident_dyna.htm) is: `(meth_name)` meth_name expects a character-like field that must contain the name of a method when the statement is executed.  Consequently, `oref->meth` is a [static method call](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abapcall_method_meth_ident_stat.htm)
- A [static component](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abenclass_component_selector.htm) comp of a class can be accessed using the name `class=>comp`.  Here, a component can be a method

Comment: I think you understood well; I wouldn't use the term "static method call" because ambiguous; is that a call of a static method, or a static call of a method :) (that's a remark, not a question) ; if you are interested in semantics, and to complexify the discussion of static versus dynamic, what is a [static type](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/index.htm?file=abenstatic_type_glosry.htm) versus a [dynamic type](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/index.htm?file=abendynamic_type_glosry.htm), and what is a "static data object" ? :)

Comment: There is a simple semantic distinction: static **call** of a method and static **method**. Simple as a pie.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Static have two meanings:
The methods (and attributes) of a class are either `static` or `instance`. In the latter case an instance of the class has to exist, to be able to call an instance method or access and instance attribute of the class. The syntax is different:

call an instance method: `oref->method`

call a static method: `class=>method`

Similarly for attributes:

static: `class=>attribute`

instance: `oref->attribute`

On the other hand the call of the method can be either `static` or `dynamic`.

Static call of a method:
`oref->method` (1) (or `class=>method` (2) )

Dynamic call of a method: `oref->(method)` (3) (or `class=>(method)` (4) )

To be exact:

(1) Static call of an instance method

(2) Static call of a static method

(3) Dynamic call of an instace method

(4) Dynamic call of a static method

Comment: That's what I thought, thanks. Unfortunately, this overloading of terms is error prone when ABAP non-experts use imprecise language